# How to use a custom buttom XML in the .KT activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have setup a custom buttom using 2 XML's for the default state and the pressed state. However, I would like to have the button keep the pressed state until I press it again. Like, the button is yellow and then I press it once and the button turns green. Then I press it again and it goes back to yellow, but keeping the custom parameters setup in the corresponding XML file (corner radius, etc).

Here are the XML files:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/function_button_pressed"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/function_button_default"/>
</selector>
```

default state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/earth_dark">
    </stroke>
    <solid android:color="@color/amber"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

pressed sate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/earth_dark">
    </stroke>
    <solid android:color="#85F142"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

I am aware the pressed state is only when the button is pressed and goes back to default when it is released.
My question is how do I implement the pressed state within my code in the MainActivity.kt(...or within the XML....) and have it stay until I change it

Thank you in advance for any help.

Ray.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is some sort of `CompoundButton` – e.g., a `ToggleButton` – and `android:state_checked` instead.

Comment: let me look into that. You mean `android:state_checked` in the XML, instead of `android:state_pressed`?

Comment: Yep, in your `<selector>` drawable. You're basically describing checkbox behavior, yeah? (Btw, the `CheckBox` class is a `CompoundButton`, too; I mentioned `ToggleButton` just 'cause it seemed closer to your design.)

Comment: That was it. That is what I was looking for, and it worked out great. Many thanks Mike.